# Calculate average with mongoose using aggregate framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am struggling to solve this problem. I use mongoose in a Node.js backend and need to find the average of a field in a big dataset. There are around 1.500.000 documents in the db, which is why I tried to use the `model.aggregate()` function:

```js
const vxxEntry = require("../model/vxxEntry");

const getAvg = async function () {
    return vxxEntry.aggregate([
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: null,
                    avgVolume: {$avg: "$volume"}
                }
            },
        ],
        {
            allowDiskUse: true
        }
    )
}
```

The model looks like this:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const {Decimal128} = require("mongodb");

const vxxEntrySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    timestamp: { type: Date},
    price: { type: Decimal128},
    volume: { type: Number},
    exchange: { type: String},
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("vxxEntry", vxxEntrySchema);
```

The problem is that the function `getAvg()` always returns:

```js
[ { _id: null, avgVolume: null } ]
```

Thankful for any solutions!

**Edit**

The same happens when I run the query in the native mongo shell!

Running the following returns a big array of objects so I think the collection and the field do exist.

```js
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$volume"
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to run the native query through mongo shell? In this sense, you can isolate the problem between mongoose/javascript adoption and the database query itself.

Comment: The syntax is correct, my guess either your schema does not match your data or you're using a wrong collection name.